# Un-merge the column into two columns using pandas python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe generated using pivot table which looks like this

[image]

I want to unmerge the column Score column and it should be like below picture , I want to split the column `Score` in to two columns.

[image]

I tried this code but it split into two rows instead of column

```
final_df = final_df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split(' ').explode())
```

[image]

Comment: Is your dataframe multi-indexed or is that rank just fluff from your IDE?

Comment: @Jeff Yes `index=['PhotoID','ID']`

Comment: If I'm understanding your dataframe's indexing correctly, you currently have a problem with the indexing after the split. For example after you split `df['Score'][1]`, your two new columns are both still indexed by `df['Score'][1]`

Comment: Perhaps this is what you want? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491274/pandas-split-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns

Comment: @Jeff I got result using `df['Score'][1]` but the names are changed I want in the same format as shown above

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.